# How to add a circle animation in android app like musixmatch?

Tags: java, android, animation

[image: Musixmatch Circle animation]

I have an app that records an audio. I wanna add an animation which is a circle like that of a musixmatch. Please recommend me on how to achieve like that.

Comment: a long time ago I used this library, I don’t know if it works now https://github.com/booncol/Pulsator4Droid

Comment: Thanks bro, It works like a charm.